# How to save file exisited in s3 to django filefield

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-storage

I have video model with two filefields (media stored in amazon s3):

```
class Video(models.Model):
    original = FileField(storage=S3BotoStorage())
    small = FileField(storage=S3BotoStorage(), null=True)
```

I'm upload only original video, then after uploading I create converting job in amazon elastic transcode (and I specified filepath for converted file).

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Video)
def handle_new_video(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        send_transcode_job_request(instance.id, 'converted/file.mp4')
```

When job is completed I want to save only filepath to file to `small` filefield.

```
@receiver(job_completed, sender=Video)
def handle_converting_completed(video_id, filepath, **kwargs):
    video = Video.objects.get(id=video_id)
    video.small.file.name = filepath
```

How to do this without re-uploading video?

Comment: Are you using any external module in order to operate with boto inside FileField?